# Matplotlib bar plot not changing color on condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataset that consist of three columns: `username` `scores` `team` and I need to bar plot the username on X axis and the scores on Y axis for each of the team in one graph, for team there's two values: `Ambios` and `Goddess`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\users\\USER\\Documents\\Dataset_file\\team_dataset.xlsx")

ambios = data[data['team'] == 'Ambios']
amb_user = data[data['team'] == 'Ambios']['username']
amb_scores = data[data['team'] == 'Ambios']['scores']

goddess = data[data['team'] == 'Goddess']
goddess_user = data[data['team'] == 'Goddess']['username']
goddess_scores = data[data['team'] == 'Goddess']['scores']

color_val = []
for i in data['team'].values:
    if i == 'Ambios':
        color_val.append('orange')
    elif i == 'Goddess':
        color_val.append('blue')

plt.style.use('ggplot')

plt.bar(amb_user,amb_scores,label='Ambios',color=color_val)
plt.bar(goddess_user,goddess_scores,label='Goddess',color=color_val)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Main problem is the bar plot color didn't not changes for the `Goddess` team.

The graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because plotting already filtered rows only pass color name instead list:

```
plt.bar(amb_user,amb_scores,label='Ambios',color='orange')
plt.bar(goddess_user,goddess_scores,label='Goddess',color='blue')
```